# Show top of *Async Shell Command* buffer

Tags: process, shell-command

Is there a way to get to the top of a buffer that is not necessarily active?

What I want to do is run a shell command on the word at point and then show the top of the output in the `*Async Shell Command*` buffer (if the output is longer than the screen).

What I have now is:

```el
(evil-leader/set-key "l"
  (lambda ()
    (interactive)
    (async-shell-command
     (concat "parse " (thing-at-point 'word 'no-properties)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't want to use `async-shell-command` but `start-process` instead.  That will let you decide when and how you display the output.

E.g. something like (guaranteed 100% untested):

```
(defun my-parse-command ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ((buf (get-buffer-create "*my-output-buffer*"))
         (proc (start-process
                "my-parse-proc" buf
                "parse" (thing-at-point 'word 'no-properties))))
    (set-process-sentinel
     proc
     (lambda (proc _state)
       (with-current-buffer (process-buffer proc)
         (save-excursion
           (goto-char (point-min))
           (if (>= (line-beginning-position 2) (point-max))
               ;; A single line of output, show in echo area
               (message "%s" (buffer-substring))
             (let ((win (display-buffer (current-buffer))))
               (when win
                 (fit-window-to-buffer win))))))))))
```